# Why SqlParameter always set parameter is null?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlparameter

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    cmd.CommandText = p;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("--");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.Connection.Open();
    foreach (var parameter in filters)
    {
        var type = parameter.Value.GetType();
        var param = new SqlParameter(parameter.Id, parameter.Value);
        param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        param.Value = parameter.Value;

        cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
    dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
    cmd.Connection.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

Here is my code.
Variable "p" is my sqlQuery string.
Variable "filters" is my parameter list.
For example: parameter.Id = "@offerId" (as string) and parameter.Value = 1230 (as Integer)
Also my query is like that : "`select  *  from Offers where  ID = @offerID and IsActive = @isActive`"

when pass into cmd.ExecuteReader(), in IntelliTrace shows my query like that:

```
--The data may be truncated and may not represent the query that was run on the server
USE [DB];

GO

--Type and value data was not available for the following variables. Their values have been set to defaults.
DECLARE @offerID AS SQL_VARIANT;
DECLARE @isActive AS SQL_VARIANT;
SET @offerID = NULL;
SET @isActive = NULL;

select  *  from Offers where  ID = @offerID and IsActive = @isActive
```

We tried lots of method for set. But always variables set null.

Comment: var param = new SqlParameter(parameter.Id, parameter.Value);, should it be var param = new SqlParameter(parameter.Id, /*your column data type, int or etc, SqlDbType.Something*/);

Comment: thanks. but we tried that.

Comment: could you show the contents (obfuscated, if required) of your filters collection?

Comment: how about cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.Id, parameter.Value); or 
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter.Id, parameter.Value); directly without new variable declared ?

Comment: also, put a breakpoint on your parameter to make sure it has the correct name(@offerID) and value as expected

Comment: if your parameter.Value is null, change it to DBNull.Value for sql to understand it

Comment: We tried all of this. But don't work. An interested thing is
 no exception, also seems no problem in debug.

Comment: what if hardcoded the value for testing, will it work?

Comment: We tried hardcoded test...

Comment: I tihnk you do not need to do this again param.Value = parameter.Value;

Comment: Show us how have you declared and used filters variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliTrace currently only supports this kind of type information for log files from [MMA scenarios](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/02/10/jump-to-sql-with-intellitrace.aspx). In your scenario, the type information from SqlParameter isn't collected; as a result all the variables in the query default to SQL_VARIANT with null values.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code on Visual Studio 2010 and SQL Server 2008 I tried to reproduce your scenario (or at least what I thought your scenario was **as you weren't very specific**).
I created these tables: Q25682067 *using int for the offer id and bit for the 'isActive' field*; and Q25682067_Offers with **sql_variant** for each field, as suggested by your post.

```
CREATE TABLE [Q25682067]([ID] [int] NOT NULL, [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL) ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE TABLE [Q25682067_Offers]([ID] [sql_variant] NOT NULL,[IsActive] [sql_variant] NOT NULL ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Data pairs (1,false) and (1,true) added to each table.
Now considering your filters are something like:

```
var filters = new Parameter[] { 
    new Parameter() {Id="@offerID ", Value=1},
    new Parameter() {Id="@isActive", Value=false}
};
```

where a Parameter might very swiftly be (without any consideration to OOP practices):

```
internal class Parameter
{
   public string Id;
   public object Value;
}
```

Now, this populates the data table:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Q25682067 where ID = @offerID and IsActive = @isActive";
```

this does not:

```
cmd.CommandText = "select * from Q25682067_Offers where ID = @offerID and IsActive = @isActive";
```

Using the SqlParameter constructor like that binds your parameters to SqlDbType.Int and SqlDbType.Bit instead of SqlDbType.Variant, which seems to be your weapon of choice. That's why your code works with the first table definition, and not the second.